# Force HTTPs rule only partially works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I am using the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://websitename.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If I type in `websitename.com` into a browser, it will display the website as `http://websitename.com`.

If I type in `www.websitename.com` into a browser, it will display the website as `https://websitename.com`.

I'm not really sure why this is happening, as using the above code from the .htaccess file it should be displaying using `https://` regardless, not only if `www.` is included within the URL.

There are no other rules within the .htaccess file.

I have tried some variations, which are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

as well as:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [OR]
```

Both produce the same result. All testing has been carried out without cache.

Comment: Did you try testing from a new browser or clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @anubhava yes, I have tried using Chrome, Firefox and Edge as well as with a cleared cache.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but don't do basic HTTP(S) troubleshooting using a browser as various settings in it can change behaviour (more and more of them over time will switch to HTTPS by default first, or even only). Use a low level tool like `curl` or `wget` and look at verbose output to see the redirections in place or not, but with those you can clearly specify `http://` or `https://` to have clear pictures of what is happening.

Comment: @Joe: Can you share your `VirtualHost` configurations for ssl and non-ssl sites?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Comment: To help debug this, temporarily remove your existing rule and try the following: `RewriteRule ^foo$ /?HTTPS=%{HTTPS} [R,L]` and request `/foo` over both HTTP and HTTPS. What are the resulting URLs you are redirected to?

Comment: @anubhava Your links do not prove your position at all (besides being 10 years old), they say "they fit both" (websites), so it remains a matter of subjective judgement. "most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks." by the same logic you can say lots of other configuration in lots of other software is created and maintained by developers so if anything a developer touch becomes immediately a development topic, then that caters for lots f things, and I certainly don't agree. You are free to judge other votes the way you want.

Comment: @anubhava Parts of the content of your links even hint that it should be a better fit for [webmaster.se]  anyway. I think there is a confusion between "there are things looking as programming inside rewrite rules/.htaccess" (as you can certainly think regex as mini programming languages for once) and "the file is edited by a developer to put VERY BASIC statement and hence should be considered development". I would agree on questions dealing the programming part of regex in rewrite rules for example as being on topic, but basic instructions and "it does not work" certainly not.